# Asp.net core MVC (Frontend) + Laravel API (Backend). Authenticate using JWT

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jwt, frontend, laravel-api

Is it possible to use Authentication/Authorization using the generated **JWT from Backend Project** in the Frontend project, to secure some controllers and Actions?

Example:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize("CanView")]
public IAciton OnlyAuthorizedUsersCanView()
{
   return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible , you must save token to local storage which you sent backend.
And you must send token to controller as Bearer Token .

Sorry, I dont know English well :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance.  I have done what you suggested already, however my concern was about authorizing the user when (the user) try to browse specific control. I had edited my question with an example.

As of your English language, your explanation was very understandable. :)